# insertion sort lower bound and why it compare to `1/(2^n)`?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, tree, complexity-theory

> I have one question:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/rC92pPO]

1. we know `n!*(1/(2^n))`  compared to `2^n`, but what about insertion sort why it compare to `1/(2^n)`?

I means why unlike the example for insertion sort reverse of `2^n`was used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use at most c(n) comparisons (with two possible outcomes) on an f(n) fraction of the inputs, we need f(n) n! ≤ 2^c(n). In the display formula they're using c(n) = n (which is a little too simple because they need to consider the asymptotic constant, but whatever) and f(n) = 1/2^n, yielding the desired formula n!/2^n ≤ 2^n <=> n! ≤ 4^n, which fails for large n.

Presumably the referenced part of the textbook goes over this, but f(n) n! is the number of inputs we need to distinguish, and 2^c(n) is the number of inputs we can distinguish with c(n) comparisons.

Comment: So the text is wrong, right? For "at least half", the denominator should be 2, not 2^n? It's also weird that the next paragraph starts with "All those" when there's just *one* case there. Kinda suspect the OP left out some stuff that's actually in the book...